# Issue com.google.gdata.util.ResourceNotFoundException: Not Found with Google Analytic

Tags: java, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

**Problem description**

I am using Google analytic for show visits/ bounce rates for a website. Before yesterday functionality was working fine. But now I am getting an error

```
com.google.gdata.util.ResourceNotFoundException: Not Found
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 404 (Not Found)!!1</title>
  <style>
    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}
  </style>
  <a href=//www.google.com/><img src=//www.google.com/images/errors/logo_sm.gif alt=Google></a>
  <p><b>404.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
  <p>The requested URL <code>/analytics/feeds/accounts/default</code> was not found on this server.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>

    at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:599)
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(GoogleGDataRequest.java:564)
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.checkResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:560)
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.execute(HttpGDataRequest.java:538)
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.execute(GoogleGDataRequest.java:536)
    at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1135)
    at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:998)
    at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.getFeed(GoogleService.java:645)
    at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1017)
    at com.report.utils.GoogleAnlytics.getAvailableAccounts(GoogleAnlytics.java:41)
    at com.report.utils.GoogleAnlytics.run(GoogleAnlytics.java:113)
    at com.report.utils.GoogleAnlytics.main(GoogleAnlytics.java:164)
```

**What I did**

I am using account URL

```
"https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/accounts/default"
```

I searched about this issue on internet but couldn't find any solution.
What is the problem, and how can I solve?

Comment: It is gone, baby, gone. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12104801/gapi-account-data-url-goes-to-404

Answer (score 3):

The feed has been shut down by Google. See [Account Feed Shutdown](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-analytics-api-notify/dcdz3LzKnpA)

> The [Data Export API v2.3 migration](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-analytics-api-notify/bS0XrfpBlOU/discussion) has completed and the API has been shutdown. If your application attempts to access the Account Feed it will now receive a 404 error response. To resolve this error, [migrate](https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/articles/gdata-migration-guide) to the [Management API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/) to access configuration data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply i have followed the given link and i have made changes accordingly like follows https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v2.4/management/accounts?start-index=1&max-results=100&key=API_KEY and Data URL to https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v2.4/data still i am getting com.google.gdata.util.ParseException: [Line 1, Column 1567, element entry] Required extension element http://schemas.google.com/analytics/2009:tableId not found.

Comment: after doing some Rnd now I am getting new error as com.google.gdata.util.ServiceForbiddenException: Forbidden <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><errors xmlns="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005"><error><domain>GData</domain><code>insufficientPermissions</code><internalReason>User does not have permission to perform this operation</internalReason></error></errors> i don't know what went wrong in code ?

Answer (score 0):

follow this `https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v2/mgmtJava` change account profile url to `https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v2.4/management/accounts/~all/webproperties/~all/profiles`, And use ManagementFeed / ManagementEntry instead of AccountFeed and AccountEntry
I have solved my problem :))