# gapi account data url goes to 404

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Does anyone know the new account data url used by the GAPI 1.3.1 class? The current one is

https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/accounts/default but it goes to a 404

Regards,

Comment: Ah, the end is nigh. For those who thought deprecated didn't mean 'not working,' well...in this case...it really means not working. Google was serious when they sent out multiple warnings about this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Go to : https: // code.google.com /apis/console/
- Login and create a new project
- Turn on Analytics API
- Click on Analytics API link and then in the left menu choose API Access
- Note down the API Key (Key for browser apps )

Then inside your code, where you had:
https: // www.google.com/ analytics/feeds/accounts/default
will be replaced with:
https://  www. googleapis.com/ analytics /v2.4/management/accounts

There is one more change to do.
Each call for info will have to also include the API Key as a GET param named key

Example: https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v2.4/management/accounts?start-index=1&max-results=100&key=**API_KEY**

I am sorry, I am new here and I can't paste links yet. Hope to get better :)

Answer (score 4):

Account data url:
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v2.4/management/accounts/~all/webproperties/~all/profiles

Report data url:
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v2.4/data

Comment: Thanks Guzel, this is the correct url to access the account details

Comment: Thank you so much for answer. I have a small issue. I replaced it with
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v2.4/management/accounts/~all/webproperties/~all/profiles
but i am not getting the Key "accountName" on the response. What should i do to get accountName with response?

Answer (score 1):

See [Account Feed Shutdown](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-analytics-api-notify/dcdz3LzKnpA)

> The [Data Export API v2.3 migration](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-analytics-api-notify/bS0XrfpBlOU/discussion) has completed and the API has been shutdown. If your application attempts to access the Account Feed it will now receive a 404 error response. To resolve this error, [migrate](https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/articles/gdata-migration-guide) to the [Management API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/) to access configuration data.

Answer (score 0):

While using GAPI 1.3.1, you can request a list of accounts available to the user by calling the list method for accounts. In PHP this will look like:

```
try {
    $accounts = $analytics->management_accounts->listManagementAccounts();
} catch (apiServiceException $e) {
    print 'There was an Analytics API service error ' . $e->getCode() . ':' . $e->getMessage();
} catch (apiException $e) {
    print 'There was a general API error ' . $e->getCode() . ':' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

See https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtAccountGuide for more details about querying the GA Management API with GAPI.