# Updated Google Analytic API and older version

Tags: asp.net, google-analytics, google-api

Before Google Analytic Update there api  this code works.

```
    string userName = GAEmailAddress.ToString();//Its From Database
    string passWord = GAPassword.ToString();//Its From Database

    const string dataFeedUrl = "https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/data";


    AccountQuery query = new AccountQuery();
    AnalyticsService service = new AnalyticsService("AnalyticsApp");
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName))
    {
        service.setUserCredentials(userName, passWord);
    }
    string str = "";
    try
    {
        AccountFeed accountFeed = service.Query(query);
        foreach (AccountEntry entry in accountFeed.Entries)
        {
            str = entry.ProfileId.Value;
        }

        DataQuery query1 = new DataQuery(dataFeedUrl);
        // Bounce Rate Calculations
        query1.Ids = str;
        query1.Metrics = "ga:visits,ga:bounces";//visitors
        query1.Sort = "ga:visits";
        query1.GAStartDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1).AddDays(-2).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        query1.GAEndDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        query1.StartIndex = 1;

  //Others code and other data for bound
```

I search in SO and and Find this link.

[gapi account data url goes to 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12104801/gapi-account-data-url-goes-to-404)

I replace this link :

`const string dataFeedUrl = "https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/data";`

with:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v2.4/management/accounts?start-index=1&max-results=100&key=API_KEY
```

But I still I gett error:

```
Execution of request failed: https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/accounts/default
```

I still search and find this link:

[https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v2/#register](http://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v2/#register)

As link says I replace :

```
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v2.4/data
```

But still I got error ? What I am missing here? Thanks.

Comment: have you read this redlined remark at the top of the doc: **The Data Export API Account Feed is no longer supported. All requests for configuration data should instead be made through the Management API**.

Comment: And you should seriously go for the OAuth2 Registration flow with your app since all of the Google Apis are going down that road almost to SSO kind of service (which makes absolute sense from my point of view).